# Find the expected value of the sum of $m$ randomly numbers in the set $\{0,1,2,...,n\}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

If you choose randomly $m$ numbers without replace in the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Calculate the average of the sum of the $m$ chosen numbers.

I was thinking the if $S$ is the random value that have distinct values, where the minimum value is $0+1+2+\cdots +m-1=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ and the maximum value is $(n-m+1)+(n-m+2)+ \cdots + n =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{(n-m)(n-m+1)}{2} $.

Then
$$E(S) = \sum_{s} sP(S=s)$$
But I don't know if am I doing this right?

Comment: One easy way to calculate this average is to pair up samples — for each sample $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m\}$ there's a sample $\{n-x_1, n-x_2, \ldots, n-x_m\}$. The mean value of the sum of these two samples must be twice the mean value of one, since there's a one-to-one mapping from the set of samples onto itself.

Answer (score 1):

Average of an arithmetic progression is the average of the first and last terms, which in this case is $~ \displaystyle \frac {n}{2}$. As we randomly choose $m$ terms, the average sum of $m$ terms should be $\displaystyle \frac{mn}{2}$.

Comment: @tommik yes that's correct but it is _average_ of the sum of randomly chosen $m$ terms in an arithmetic progression which should follow the mean? For example, average of sum of $n$ terms in the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, ... n \}$ should be $n^2/2$, average of sum of $2$ terms should be $n$...

Comment: I don't follow, can you explain more, please?

Comment: @Marinela if you sum all the terms, you get $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and as there are $(n+1)$ terms, dividing you get the average value of a term in A.M as $\frac{n}{2}$ which is nothing but sum of first and last term divided by $2$. Now as there are $m$ terms, you get average sum as $ \frac {m n} {2}$. In fact you found average of min and max sum separately. If you sum both and divided by $2$, that would give you the average sum as well.

Answer (score 1):

In other words we want to calculate the expectation of $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{i\cdot a_{i}}$ where $m$ of the $a_{i}$s are $1$ and the rest are $0$.

$$
\begin{align}
E\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}{i\cdot a_{i}}\right)&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{i\cdot E\left(a_{i}\right)}\\
\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{i\cdot\frac{m}{n+1}}\\
\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\cdot\frac{m}{n+1}\\
\\
&=\frac{mn}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$E(a_1+ \cdots + a_m) = E((n-a_1) + \cdots + (n-a_m)) = nm - E(a_1+\cdots + a_m)$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use indicator like variables here. We take advantage of the linearity of expectation.

Let $S = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m X_i$ where each $X_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ value you pulled.

$\mathbb{E}[S] = \mathbb{E}[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^m X_i] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m\mathbb{E}[X_i]$.

Even though the $X_i$ are *not* independent and it might be the case that even one of them is completely determined. (For example if $m=n$ and you pulled $2,3,...,n-1,n $ then you know that $X_n=1$ for certainty)

Despite all of this the expected value of each $X_i$ is the same. It should be clear that prior to seeing anything all $X_i$ have the same distribution. The fourth number you pull is just as likely to be a $7$ as the first number before you do anything.

Hence $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mathbb{E}[X_1] = \frac{n}{2}$

And so $\mathbb{E}[S] = \mathbb{E}[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^m X_i] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^m\mathbb{E}[X_i] =\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \frac{n}{2} = \frac{nm}{2}$.

Comment: I just don't get all that $\mathbb{E}[X_{i}]=\frac{n}{2}$, I mean, $\mathbb{E}[X_{i}] = \sum_{x} x \mathbb{P}(X_{i}=x| X1=x_{1}, X_{2}=X_{2}, \ldots, X_{i-1}=x_{i-1})$, is like this?